# Move files to sFTP

Tags: datastage

I gotta move a couple of files from our DataStage server directories to an outside sFTP, the connect has been set and i have HTTP URL, SFTP URL, user and password. Any idea how can I reach that in DataStage.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP Connector stage should be able to handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write some scripts for same activity, if you are struggling with FTP connector stage.

Sample [Shell script](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/232853-shell-scripting-creating-ftp-transfer-file.html).

Comment: Hi Vibhor, Can you give and example how can I write the script in the Execute Command to do that.

Comment: I have added some reference for your over my original response.  ou can execute script on Execute Command stage.